# Codeigniter links trouble

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, hyperlink

I am using codeigniter framework for my college project, and I having some problems with links, when i do something like this in my view:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('Controller_test/testFunction') ?>">CLICK ME</a>
</li>
```

It all works great, but when I try to put link inside my array for example `CLICK ME` link, like this:

```
$links = array(
    'links' =>
        "<li class='dropdown'>" . 
            "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>TEST links <span class='caret'></span></a>" . 
            "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>" . 
                "<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Controller_test/testFunction') ?>">CLICK ME</a></li>" . 
                "<li><a href='#'>TEST 1</a></li>" . 
                "<li><a href='#'>TEST 2</a></li>" . 
            "</ul>" . 
        "</li>"
);
```

the problem occurs. I cannot understand where I make mistake. Thanks to everyone willing to help me!

Comment: Remove php tag form `site_url()`

Comment: What error message do you have?

Comment: For Saty: if you think like this : 


    . "<li> <a href="<?php echo ('Controller_test2/testFunction') ?>">CLICK ME</a> </li>" 
For comrade:
the problem is Syntax error

Comment: Use it as `. "<li> <a href='".site_url('Controller_test/testFunction')."'>CLICK ME</a> </li>"`

Comment: To Stay that's solves my problem
Thanks a lot, post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are written  php tag inside php tag . Need to rewrite your code as

```
 $links = array(
                'links' =>"<li class='dropdown'>"
                . "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' >TEST links <span class='caret'></span></a>"
                . "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>"
                . "<li> <a href='".site_url('Controller_test/testFunction')."'>CLICK ME</a> </li>"
                . "<li> <a href='#'>TEST 1</a> </li>"
                . "<li> <a href='#'>TEST 2</a> </li>"
                . "</ul>"
                . "</li>"   
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're pointing to a controllers method. You can not use controller method . take a look at the documentation [Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

You should use something like this

```
site_url('url-link');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inside `php` while declaring `$links` variable. Change the `site_url` line to

`<a href="site_url('Controller_test/testFunction') ?>">CLICK ME</a> </li>"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check it.

    $links = array(
        'links' =>
            "<li class='dropdown'>
                <a href=".site_url('Controller_test/testFunction1')." class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>TEST links <span class='caret'></span></a> 
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><a href=".site_url('Controller_test/testFunction').">CLICK ME</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>TEST 1</a></li> 
                    <li><a href='#'>TEST 2</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li>"
    );


    OR

    $links = array(
        'links' =>
            "<li class='dropdown'>
                <a href=".base_url().'Controller_test/testFunction1'" class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>TEST links <span class='caret'></span></a> 
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><a href=".base_url().'Controller_test/testFunction'">CLICK ME</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>TEST 1</a></li> 
                    <li><a href='#'>TEST 2</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li>"
    );
```